# Text is smaller in fractions in multiline equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations, fontsize

The text size shrinks in a multiline equation when I use fractions. How can I keep it the same as the non-multiline equation size?

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
    p = -\frac{1}{\chi}\text{div}(\mathbf{u}),\\
    \rho \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} = - \nabla p.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

I need it the same size as this -

```
\begin{equation}
 p = -\frac{1}{\chi}\text{div}(\mathbf{u})
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` will force the fraction to display at the "usual" size.

Hence using this code will work:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        p = -\dfrac{1}{\chi}\mathrm{div}(\mathbf{u}),\\
        \rho \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} = - \nabla p.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Edit: As suggested by Manuel, using `\dcases` is a better alternative

The code becomes

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{dcases}
        p = -\frac{1}{\chi}\mathrm{div}(\mathbf{u}),\\
        \rho \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} = - \nabla p.
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: May be better use `dcases` instead of `cases`?

Comment: you also need amsmath package for these commands to work

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `dcases` environment provided by `mathtools`. Note also some improvements to your code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
p=-\frac{1}{\chi}\Div\vect{u}, \\
\rho\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}=-\nabla p
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A further improvement for the partial derivative: with

```
\newcommand{\pder}[3][]{%
  \frac{\partial\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else^{#1}\fi#2}
       {\partial#3\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else^{#1}\fi}%
}
```

in the preamble, you can use

```
\pder{f}{t}
\pder[2]{f}{t}
\pder{}{t}
\pder[2]{}{t}
```

and your case would be the last one.